# Adding F# to Visual Studio 2010 C# express - is it possible?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, visual-studio-express

My question relates to:
[will there be a F# express edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977132/will-there-be-a-f-express-edition)

Given there is no VS 2010 F# express - I would like to know what the latest wisdom is for installing F# onto VS 2010 C# express. Is it possible at all?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Note that a release today enables F# inside the free VS2010 shell, offering an express-like F# experience.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2010/08/17/announcing-the-f-2-0-free-tools-for-net-4-0.aspx