# Is it possible to develop f# using Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-express

I have been doing some programming in VB.NET on Visual Studio Express 2015 for Desktop. I recently started looking into F# and like the functional paradigm. As a result I have been trying to find a way to use VSE2015 as my IDE for F#. However, I have hit some problems. First of all, it has been difficult to find out if it is officially supported. The .NET blog suggests that it is (at least [version 3.1.1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2014/01/22/announcing-visual-f-tools-3-1-1-with-support-for-desktop-and-web-express/), and the [announcement for 4.0 RTM does not mention otherwise](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/20/announcing-the-rtm-of-visual-f-4-0/)), but when I try to install F# Tools (4.0) it seems to choke on some components called VWD and WD(?). 3.1.1 seems to install OK, but then I still can't open any F# projects (fsproj). When I try to install FSharpVSPowerTools, it tells me that my platform is not supported.

Am I trying to do something that is not possible? Have I missed some steps? Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks.

(Incidentally, I can't use the Community edition because of the licensing restrictions) 
Edit: I have tried VS Code, but it works differently from VSE, and I would have to do a whole more learning. In addition, I want to use the VS template for creating XLL's. Edit 2: it has been pointed out that you can reference excel-dna in VS Code, but setting it up is not as straightforward as in VSE2015 (at least for VB.NET and C#.NET.

Comment: Even if you can you might not be able to install Visual F# Power Tools in Express as you found out. You should really a) consider using Community Edition b) VSCode with Ionide-fsharp.

Comment: This can help you  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/using-visual-studio-to-write-fsharp-programs

Comment: Unfortunately, as I mentioned, I cannot use the Community Edition. I have tried VS Code, but it does not seem so straightforward. Does it have a template for XLL using excel-dna (or some other straightforward method)?

Comment: That's a separate issue. I don't see the difference between doing that in VS2015 or Code, you would install excel-dna from nuget, and create a library project and compile it to .xll. As you found out unfortunately VS Express is not straightforward for your scenario. It might be possible to make it work (might not) so give it a few days, but I would rather explore other approaches, incl. VS2015 Professional etc if neither Community nor Code works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the MSDN document, which is generally helpful. The reference to Community Edition is less helpful, because I explicitly excluded it. Perhaps someone else will find it useful, though.

Comment: Thanks to s952163 for the clarification (which I had not seen when I wrote my latest response). The pointer to excel-dna on nuget is helpful, although I have tried it and not found it so straightforward. My basic question is still about VSE2015 and f# since I want to get a group of part-time programmers generating code and I don't want them to have to learn multiple packages and we can't pay for full licenses for all, since some may only do it on a handful of occasions in a year.

Comment: Does this mean that MS no longer supports f# tools for VSE2015, despite declaring support in the past?

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3287157/adding-f-to-visual-studio-2010-c-sharp-express-is-it-possible?rq=1) also mentions VSE2010 access to f#.

Comment: Probably you ran into [this issue](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2015/07/20/announcing-the-rtm-of-visual-f-4-0/) at the very bottom of the page. So the question is if 4.0.0.1 has fixed it, or are there any workarounds. What happens if you install latest Visual F# tools, then install VS2015 Express?

Comment: Thanks to s952163 - I had visited that page, but had not spotted that comment. I will try to uninstall vse2015 and then install the Visual F# tools. I will report back, although not for a day or so.

Comment: Sorry - I should have reported back earlier. I have still not managed to get F# up and running with VSE2015, despite getting IT assistance from my company. However... I did manage to get F# running with VS Code... but I don't really understand what I managed to do, and it is still not the workflow that I am looking for. I am going to try to get my company to pay for a licensed version of VS. Thanks.